# How to fix " Could not find/open font when opening font arial..." and blurred png with Gnuplot 4.6 and AIX 7.2?

Tags: linux, gnuplot, aix

I've this error with AIX 7.2 :

```
Could not find/open font when opening font "arial", using internal non-scalable font
```

And I don't know how to fix it... Any idea ?

Do you think that this error could be the source of the fact that my graph is " blurred " ?

[image: image_1]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/36/1/1567414607-discord.jpg))</sub>

Here my gnuplot script :

```
set title "df -g command test"
set terminal png truecolor size 720,480 background rgb "#eff1f0"
set output "test.png"
set grid
set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 1 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1

set style line 2 \
    linecolor rgb "red" \
    linetype 1 linewidth 1 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1

set offsets 0.5,0.5,0,0.5
set datafile separator ","
set ylabel " MB BLOCK "
set xlabel " Date "
set format y "%g"
myLabel(n) = sprintf("%g",n)

plot "XXXXX" using 2:xtic(1) with linespoints linestyle 1 title "MB used", \
'' using 3:xtic(1) with linespoints linestyle 2 title " Free space ", \
'' using 0:2:(myLabel($2)) w labels offset 0,1.5 notitle, \
'' using 0:3:(myLabel($3)) w labels offset 0,1.5 notitle
```

If I try this script ( without the free space curve ) with RedHat 7.6, my png looks great :
[image: image_2]
<sub>(source: [noelshack.com](https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/36/1/1567414962-test.png))</sub>

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Check if you have arial font installed. For example: `fc-list | grep -i arial`: it should find files like `/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType/arial.ttf`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I change :

```
set terminal png truecolor size 720,480 background rgb "#eff1f0"
```

To :

```
set terminal pngcairo truecolor size 720,480 background rgb "#eff1f0" font "Arial"
```

And it's great.